# Google Map with Sidebar that Zooms to a Specific Location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, menu, sidebar

I'm working on a javascript Google map where I have marked the location of each of the state capitals with a custom marker and a title of that capital and state. Right now when you view the map you see the whole US with each marker. I want to keep that but add a sidebar where you click the name of a state and the map zooms to the state and capital. I would also like to add a link that zooms out view the full map. Does anyone have a tutorial on how to do this? I found several examples of Google maps with sidebars but none that zooms to a specific location.

Edit:
This is what I am trying to achieve: http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_map2.htm
Here is the code I am working with:

```
<script>
function init() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.781494, -96.064453),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
   };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var image = 'Alabama.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.366805, -86.299969);
    var AlabamaMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title:"Montgomery, Alabana"   
    });     
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

</script>
```

Comment: [Example from Mike Williams' tutorial ported to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate listeners (for example, using jquery) with the click event on your state names. Provided they had an id attribute with the USPS code, it would be something like

```
  jQuery(document).on('click','#RESET',function() {
        map.setZoom(5);
        map.setCenter({lat:41, lng:-89.5});
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','#CA',function() {
        map.setZoom(7);
        map.setCenter({lat:36.4, lng:-120.9});
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click','#FA',function() {
        map.setZoom(7);
        map.setCenter({lat:28, lng:-81});
    });
```

You see, I included one link with id RESET that allows me to reset to the initial state.

Here you can see it at work
http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/38e0541592bf331cb298

Comment: I like the way you set up the map and is what I'm looking for but I am not familiar with jquery. Is it possible to do this in javacript?

Comment: Yes, although what you see in my answer is all the jQuery you need to know to set listeners on certain elements. You could use onclick attribute on the button elements.